# How to Write Scope in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am upgrading an app from Rails 3.2 to 4.0.  I would like to know if the scope below is still valid in 4.0 or if I need to rewrite it.  I am not finding anything on the web for how to do such a scope in Rails 4.

```
scope :cash_by_employee_position_id, lambda{  {
      :select => "SUM(dir_cash_tips) as cash, emplid, position_id",
      :joins => "INNER JOIN employees_micros on tips.micro_id = employees_micros.micro_id",
      :group => "emplid, position_id",
      :order => "emplid" }}
```

If this is not valid any longer, how would I do it in 4.0?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think this is some Rails 2 code, pasted to Rails 3 (which deprecated this). Try the following: `lambda { select("SUM(dir_cash_tips) as cash, emplid, position_id").joins("INNER JOIN employees_micros on tips.micro_id = employees_micros.micro_id").group("emplid, position_id").order("emplid") }`

Comment: Thanks, I won't know if this works until I get many more of these changed along with other stuff.  Sigh!  Maybe in the console...

Comment: Yes you can try this in the console. See if the generated SQL is matching your expectations